# Method chaining in JS

Tags: javascript, oop, methods

let's say this :

```
var method = function(number) {
  this.number = number;

  this.add = function(param) {
    this.number = this.number + param;
    return this
  }
  this.multiply = function(param) {
    this.number = this.number * param;
    return this.number
  }

}
```

If I do :

```
var newMeth = new method(2);
var result = newMeth.add(2).multiply(2);
console.log(result) // Will return 8
```

But my main concern is if I want to do :

```
var newMeth = new method(2);
var result = newMeth.add(2);
```

> I would like to know how it would be possible in that case that result
>   return me "4" instead of `method {number: 4, add: ƒ, multiply: ƒ}`

But still return me 8 if I do

```
var result = newMeth.add(2).multiply(2);
```

Any help would be appreciate. Thank you all.

Comment: You can't do this *directly*. I don't think you can convince `console.log` to ue any particular value to represent your object. Most likely, it's impossible in the general case, as `console.log` is heavily implementation dependant. However, you can have a method on your object that returns your value - `new method(2).add(2).multiply(7).getValue()` for example. If you name the method `valueOf` then it will be invoked when converting to primitive, so you can do `new method(2).add(2).multiply(7) + 5` and get a plain number out of the operation.

Answer (score 2):

You could define the `val()` method on your chain that would return the number, and use it like this:

```
var result = newMeth.add(2).multiply(2).val();
// OR
var result = newMeth.add(2).val();
// OR
var result = newMeth.val();
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Yeah I just wanted to know if it's possible to have a choice to return the value or to return the object depending if multiply is coming after add or not.

Comment: You can't choose the return value, nor should you. It's best to be explicit about what your code does. Implicit type conversions decreases code readability and bring bugs. `valueOf()`, as others have mentioned, is as close as it gets to "choosing return type".

Answer (score 1):

You can define a [`valueOf` method on your object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf). You can explicitly call it to get the number but it will also be implicitly called when converting the object to a primitive:

```js
var method = function(number) {
  this.number = number;

  this.add = function(param) {
    this.number = this.number + param;
    return this
  }
  
  this.multiply = function(param) {
    this.number = this.number * param;
    return this
  }
  
  this.valueOf = function() {
    return this.number;
  }
}

var num = new method(2)
  .add(3)
  .multiply(7);
console.log(num.valueOf());
console.log(num + 3);
console.log(num + " bottles on the wall");
```